Facing Python Gremlin Timeout Issue: (gremlin-3.7.0)
I am using gremlinpython==3.7.0.
I am getting Timeout Issue, while fetching the results.
Error:
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 598: {"detailedMessage":"A timeout occurred within the script [RequestMessage{, requestId=697b8a9a-d84d-4fd1-aada-6865becfcb7b, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(b184538d-19e5-407d-bad5-211e9d561299), with(evaluationTimeout, 3000), repeat([[], [inE(), outV()]]), emit(), path()]], aliases={g=g}}}]","code":"TimeLimitExceededException","requestId":"697b8a9a-d84d-4fd1-aada-6865becfcb7b","message":"A timeout occurred within the script [RequestMessage{, requestId=697b8a9a-d84d-4fd1-aada-6865becfcb7b, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(b184538d-19e5-407d-bad5-211e9d561299), with(evaluationTimeout, 3000), repeat([[], [inE(), outV()]]), emit(), path()]], aliases={g=g}}}]"}

Query:
remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection('wss://{}:{}/gremlin'.format(neptune_host, neptune_port),
                                            'g', ssl=False, timeout=5000, read_timeout=5000)
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)
#graph_result = g.with_("evaluationTimeout", 3000).V(entity_id).repeat(inE().outV()).emit().path().toList()
graph_result = g.V(entity_id).with_("evaluationTimeout", 3000).repeat(inE().outV()).emit().path().toList()
#graph_result = g.V(entity_id).repeat(inE().outV()).emit().path().toList()

for path in graph_result:
    for item in path:
        print("*"*100)
        if type(item) == Edge:
            if (item.outV.id, item.inV.id) not in unique_ids:
                unique_ids.add((item.outV.id, item.inV.id))
                results.append({
                    "src_entity_id": item.outV.id,
                    "src_entity_name": item.outV.label,
                    "target_entity_id" : item.inV.id,
                    "target_entity_name" : item.inV.label,
                    "association": item.label
                })


I have tried all the above ways but nothing working.
In AWS Neptune I have already set query_timeout to 10 minutes.
Can anyone suggest anything?

with_("evaluationTimeout", 3000) is stating that you want to limit the query execution to 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds).  Is that what you intend?

No, I want to increase my timeout to 5 minutes,  I have even increased the value for evaluationTimeout to 300000, but still facing the same issue.

and also I have noticed a thing, even though my evaluationTimeout was 3000, It didn't get timed out after 3 seconds, It's getting time out after 20 seconds.

You cannot increase the timeout using the evaluationTimeout hint in the query, you can only decrease it from whatever is set at the cluster or instance level.  Modifying the the neptune_query_timeout parameter for the cluster or instance also requires that the instance(s) be rebooted for the setting to take effect.

You can check to see what the current applied timeout is for an instance by using the /status API:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-status.html

Thanks @TaylorRiggan, the main problem was I didn't restart the neptune after changing the configuration. and also query wasn't efficient enough.
